# send discord message only if data is updated

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, discord.py

I have this discord bot that I want to send channel message when the scraped data is updated only, I haven't found a good method of implementing it and it didn't work quite well:

```
async def newdata():
await client.wait_until_ready()
counter = 0
second_counter = 0
channel = client.get_channel(1024849506258407454)
URL = "https://eu.tamrieltradecentre.com/pc/Trade"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all(class_="gold-amount"):
    list_prices.append(item.get_text(strip=True))
dict_names["Dreugh Wax"] = list_prices[0]
dict_names["Style Page: Pirate Skeletons Mask"] = list_prices[1]
dict_names["Style Page: Opal Engine Guardian Staff"] = list_prices[2]
dict_names["Tempering Alloy"] = list_prices[3]
dict_names["Chromium Plating"] = list_prices[4]
dict_names["Zircon Plating"] = list_prices[5]
dict_names["Perfect Roe"] = list_prices[6]
dict_names["Style Page: Opal Engine Guardian Dagger"] = list_prices[7]
dict_names["Kuta"] = list_prices[8]
dict_names["Heartwood"] = list_prices[9]
dict_names["Mundane Rune"] = list_prices[10]
dict_names["Style Page: Opal Engine Guardian Greatsword"] = list_prices[11]
dict_names["Hakeijo"] = list_prices[12]
dict_names["Style Page: Opal Ilambris Sword"] = list_prices[13]
dict_names["Potent Nirncrux"] = list_prices[14]
dict_names["Aetherial Dust"] = list_prices[15]
dict_names["Sealed Woodworking Writ"] = list_prices[16]
dict_names["Columbine"] = list_prices[17]
dict_names["Platinum Ounce"] = list_prices[18]
dict_names["Rosin"] = list_prices[19]
while not client.is_closed():
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
    if dict_names_second != dict_names:
        await channel.send(dict_names)
    await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

so I am storing everything in a dict from beautifulsoup and then I am sending a channel message and the script sleeps for 60 seconds and resends the data, I am trying to make it where it will only compare the old data and send again only if the data is updated, so it just sends the data one time when the bot runs and then after that only when the prices have changed.

Answer (score -1):

Try a database - could be something like sqlite and then use `SELECT` to get the data and `INSERT` to add it. Look online for a tutorial (there are loads!)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).